# Wordpress Multisite subdomains and sharing the same upload folder

Tags: multisite, directory, subdomains, uploads

**Hello,**

We wonder if you can help resolve two doubts about Wordpress structure.

We are developing a multisite in 3 languages and would like to know about these 2 things:

**1. Is it possible to develop each language of the multisite under a subdomain structure?**

**Example:**

spanish.nameofthesite.com 
*(main site)*

english.nameofthesite.com 
*(the translation of the main page in the same multisite)*

italian.nameofthesite.com 
*(the translation of the main page in the same multisite)*

**2. Is it possible in a multisite to share one single image folder, instead of cloning the image folder when creating a site in the Administration?**

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find a solution. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unsure as to what you mean. You want subdomains, and subdirectories?
2. Are you looking to save space? You *might* get away with symlinking the upload directories together, but as soon as one blog removes an image, it will disappear from disk from all of the other blogs that have the same image (seeing as it has the same filename).

This is a limitation of Wordpress: each blog has its own media IDs and, therefore, requires their own copies of the attachments, preferrably in different upload directories.

I'd find cheaper hosting rather than try to hack together a shared upload dir.